# Codeigniter on duplicate key insert

Tags: php, codeigniter, dropdown, insert-into

i want to create a condition which a user would choose whether he wants to use an input which means a database would create an auto_incremented id or he wants to use an older data which will not use new id but only use it. i have used dropdown database populate for my old input.

My Dropdown list

```
//get contractor list
    $Contractor_List = $this->foo_pro->get_list_contractors();
    $opt = array('' => '');
    foreach ($Contractor_List as $Contractor_No) {
       $opt[$Contractor_No] = $Contractor_No;
    }
    $data['con_list'] = form_dropdown('',$opt,'','ProjectID = "Contractor_No" name="contractorNo" id="" class="w3-select w3-border w3-hover-light-grey"');
```

My Controller

```
public function save_createdProject()
{   

    $data_project = array();
    $data_contractor = array();       

    //project data
    if ($this->input->post('year') === '') {
        $data_project['P_Year'] = 15;
    }else{
        $data_project['P_Year'] = $this->input->post('year');
    }
    if ($this->input->post('code') === '') {
        $data_project['Code'] = 'KO';
    }else{
        $data_project['Code'] = $this->input->post('code');
    }
    $data_project['ProjectID'] = $this->input->post('project');
    $data_project['Contract_Amount'] = $this->input->post('camount');

    //contractor data
    if ($this->input->post('cname') === '' && $this->input->post('caddress') === '') {
        $data_project['Contractor_No'] = $this->input->post('contractorNo');
    }else{
        $data_contractor['Contractor_Name'] = $this->input->post('cname');
        $data_contractor['Contractor_Address'] = $this->input->post('caddress');
    }

    $this->foo_pro->add_project($data_project, $data_contractor);

    redirect('Main/project','refresh');
    //var_dump($data);exit;
}
```

My Model

```
public function add_project($data_project, $data_contractor)
{   
    //contractor
    $this->db->insert('contractor', $data_contractor);
    $Contractor_No = $this->db->insert_id();
    //project
    $data_project['Contractor_No'] = $Contractor_No;
    $this->db->insert('project', $data_project);
    $ProjectID = $this->db->insert_id();

}
```

this here is my problem except inserting the older data which is the contractor_no 1 it creates another data that would insert as contractor_no 4.. but also i need to insert new data for new contractor_name..

[image: contractor]

Comment: Now what error you have?

Comment: i dont have an error but i want to find the right logic for my model or controller that would save another reference key data or use an old data... my problem is that whenever i save the contractor data into table it would suggest to create another row for my database table..

Comment: @Shihas i have update my problem

Comment: So, you want to only update the contractor, not create a new one?

Comment: no @JeremyJackson i dont need to update just i dont want to insert if it has an older one

Comment: So you only want to check the contractor is already registered based on the `Contractor_Name` column? If yes. You can just do that by form validation.

Comment: @Shihas if Contractor_Name was already registered the contractor_no in project column will continue without inserting new contractor_no in form_validation correct?

Comment: Yes. the new data wont insert ad the form validation results false.